# Measureability of $f$ and $\vert f \vert$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0, 1]$. If $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is defined by

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
    -\frac{1}{2},&  x\in E\\
     0,              & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then

1. $f $ is measurable or not.
2. $\vert f \vert$ is measurable or not.

For measurable function we need the set $\{x:f(x) \geq \alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but here $E$ is a non-measurable set. Please help.

Comment: $(-\infty,-1/2] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, but $f^{-1}((-\infty,-1/2]) = E$ is not measurable.

Comment: "we need..." is true, but you better make it: "it is sufficient". A lot more is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f$ is measurable then preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for every Borel set $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a subset of $[0,1]$. The characteristc function of $C$ is denoted by $1_C$. Then we have

$1_C$ is measurable  $ \iff C$ is measurable.

We have $f= -\frac{1}{2}1_E$ and $|f|=\frac{1}{2}1_E$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Ok, that means both are not measurable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, both are not measurable.